# Remover caractere ponto e virgula e espaços do ultimo email da lista de destinatários

Tags: c#, webforms

Olá, quero enviar meus emails conforme abaixo:

```
john@smith.com;john@smith.com;
```

mas está me dando erro de envio, pois está pegando o ponto e vírgula do último endereço, quando coloco os emails dessa maneira `john@smith.com;john@smith.com` sem o `;` consigo enviar normalmente, mas se o usuário digitar o `;` preciso fazer um tratamento para isso, que é o que não estou conseguindo.

Vou deixar o trecho de código abaixo, do que já tentei fazer, obrigado.

```
mail.From = new MailAddress(email);
//EmailIsValid(destinatario);
//mail.To.Add(destinatario);
string[] multiplesSend = destinatario.Split(';');
foreach (var emails in multiplesSend)
{
     string expression = "^[A-Za-z0-9\\._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\\.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}(?:[;][A-Za-z0-9\\._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\\.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}?)*";
     if (Regex.IsMatch(destinatario, expression))
           mail.To.Add(emails);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que o problema nesses casos é que o `Split` cria um campo vazio no `array`, visto que tens um `;` no fim da string.

Para resolver isso podes acrescentar um argumento ao `Split` para remover as strings que ficam vazias na lista

```
string[] multiplesSend = destinatario.Split(new char[] { ';' }, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

ou verificar se o e-mail está vazio antes de adicionar

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(emails) && Regex.IsMatch(destinatario, expression))
    mail.To.Add(emails);
```

Comment: Diogo qualquer duvida sobre formatação veja o link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help é de suma importância que você tenha esse conhecimento sendo um novo usuário.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Obrigado pela informação!